# MYSQL innodb variable innodb_log_file_size value is not accepting more than 2GB in 5.6.32

Tags: mysql, innodb

I tried to increase the innodb_log_file_size to 10G in mysql 5.6.32. After shutting down the server and moved the innodb files to another location. then changed the variable size to 10G. And started the server but mysql server is not started. so tried with 2G its working fine. It is not accepting more than that. I dont the reason behind this. can anyone help me on this?

Please find the error log details below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`innodb_log_file_size`, as of 5.6.3 can be up to `512GB / innodb_log_files_in_group`.

What value do you have for `innodb_log_files_in_group`?  There is no good reason to have a value other than 2.

Is this a 32-bit build?  Or on a 32-bit OS?

Anyway...  Since your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is only 1.0GB, there is no need to make the total log_file_sizes bigger than that.

Comment: Thanks @Rick ... innodb_log_files_in_group value is 2 and OS version detail is Linux  3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:37:38 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux....Total Mem:32519824        used : 3506340       free: 11921780           available:27117064                                                   
 And if i increase the buffer pool size will it work? or it also depends on system configs? if i want to increase it more..what should i need to?

Comment: Why do you want to increase the log_file_size??  With 32GB of RAM, the buffer_pool should be more like 20-25GB, not a mere 1GB (unless you have only a small amount of data and/or lots of other uses for RAM).

Comment: Due to a MySQL patch, the size of redo log BLOB writes is currently limited to 10% of the redo log file size.
As a result, the innodb_log_file_size should be 10 times larger than the largest BLOB data size found
(max_allowed_packet). Considering above case client informed me to increase the size as 10G. (I dont have any idea on this case So i just tried to increase the size and got that error, even if it not required to increase the size as you mentioned but i want to know the reason for why it is not accepting above 2G)

Comment: Ah, yes.  I forgot about that.  I would then argue that inserting `BLOBs` that large is not practical, even if it were possible.  (No I still don't have an answer for the question _as asked_.)  I was just talking with someone else about "chunking" large blobs -- He wanted even more than 4GB, which is impossible without chunking.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/170519/1876